# html tag <table> rowspan incorrect in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I have a table like below

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.cell-hidden{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td colspan="1" rowspan="7" >Neil</td></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr><td >Jianlin</td></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr><td >Rachel</td></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr><td >Neil</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2">total</td></tr>
</table>
```

it look correct in **chrome** ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7iTS.png)),but wrong in **safari**(mac or ipad pro),it look like:

[new questions image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcUGd.png)

How to do the same results with **chrome**
(can not change `<tg>`,sometime i need empty `<tr>`)

Comment: The issue is because of the border around the `tr` elements. It's still happening in Chrome as well, just to a lesser extent, as you can see there is a larger gap at the top of the second column The best way to solve this is to set `border-collapse: collapse` on the `table`

Comment: Check my answer. It will work for the new issue you mentioned as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can help you~

I'm using javascript and css to remove the empty tr.

**Update**: this is the updated version for your code.

```js
var trList = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
var counter = 0;
var tdTop;

if (trList) {
  trList.forEach(function(element) {
    if (element.innerHTML.length == 0) {
      element.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      var tdElement = element.querySelector('td');

      if (tdElement) {
        counter++;
        if (counter == 1) {
          tdTop = tdElement
        }
        if (tdElement.colSpan == 2) {
          counter--;
        }
      }
    }
  });
  if (tdTop) {
    tdTop.rowSpan = counter;
  }
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr:empty {
  display: none;
}

.cell-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="1" rowspan="7">Neil</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jianlin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rachel</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Neil 02</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">total</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you,this solution is work ,but i have new questtion now, i update snippet code(add new `tag` 'total') , does it any way to resolve?

Comment: OK,i update error image:new questions image ,when i add total tr,it incorret

Comment: I updated the code also. Good luck. If this answer your question please mark it as answered. To close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Their are empty tr in your Layout.
Just delete them if they are not important.

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.cell-hidden{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td colspan="1" rowspan="8" >Neil</td></tr>

  <tr><td >Jianlin</td></tr>
 
  <tr><td >Rachel</td></tr>
  
  <tr><td >Neil</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh you edited it. For what are you needing the empty tr

Comment: if i need empty `<tr>`,Is any other way?

Comment: Give me a second

Comment: because this table is dynamic,sometime i  need add `td` in `tr`,so i want to keep it,

Comment: Look at the other answer. I think that is working for you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try it with jQuery:

```
$('tr').each(function() {
   if($(this).find('td').length == 0) {
     $(this).hide();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS **:empty** selector to hide the empty <tr> tag

```css
tr:empty{
    display: none;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.cell-hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td colspan="1" rowspan="8" >Neil</td></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr><td >Jianlin</td></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr><td >Rachel</td></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr><td >Neil</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you,this solution is work ,but i have new questtion now, i update snippet code(add new `tag` 'total') , does it any way to resolve?

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it works for you. What is the new issue with tag total ?

Comment: OK,i update error image:new questions image ,when i add total `tr`,it incorret,plese help me

Comment: The same tr:empty trick will also work for the new issue you have posted. You don't have to change or add anything else.