# HTML Table - data (placeholder) is not displayed in the right cell

Tags: html

```
   <table> 
        <tr>
                <td colspan="2">4</td>
                <td colspan="7">key</td>
                <td colspan="2" rowspan="3"><!-- empty and crossed out--></td>
                <td colspan="2" rowspan="3"><!-- empty and crossed out--></td>
                <td colspan="2">value</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                <td colspan="2">5</td>
                <td colspan="4">key </td>
                <td colspan="3">calc</td>
                <td colspan="2">value</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td colspan="2">6</td>
                <td colspan="7">key</td>
                <td colspan="2">value</td>
           </tr>
    </table>
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMnh0.png)
[desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x0eF.png)

So what I have been trying for 2 days now, is that all values should be in the last column. The first one is right, but the other two are not. Pls help me! Cheers

Comment: Can you please share your expected output?

Comment: Just posted the picture of the desired outcome

Answer (score 0):

```
 <table name="productsAgencies" class="table table-striped table-bordered ">
           <tr>
               <th class="white center" style="width: 278px;">Product</th>
               <th class="white center">Crative Agency</th>
           </tr>


           <tr class="data-row" v-for="p in products"
               :key="p.id">
               <td class="underline">
                   {{p.name}}
               </td>
               <td class="underline">
                   <v-select
                           style="border: 0px;"
                           placeholder="productPlaceholder"
                           v-model="p.varName"
                           label="text"
                           :options="vars"
                   ></v-select>
               </td>
           </tr>
       </table>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with this question? (You appear to have copy pasted a random [github issue](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select/issues/1170))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what's wrong with the HTML you provided. All values are in the last column.

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table> 
    <tr>
            <td colspan="2">4</td>
            <td colspan="7">key</td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="3"><!-- empty and crossed out--></td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="3"><!-- empty and crossed out--></td>
            <td colspan="2">value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
            <td colspan="2">5</td>
            <td colspan="4">key </td>
            <td colspan="3">calc</td>
            <td colspan="2">value</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
            <td colspan="2">6</td>
            <td colspan="7">key</td>
            <td colspan="2">value</td>
       </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it maybe a Mac thing? Your code delivers the same output as mine..

Comment: @michaeldibse you're using Safari ?

Comment: @michaeldibse If the snippet above reproduces the issue for you, it might be worth adding your OS and browser (with version numbers) to the question.

Comment: Yes I do. Ok one moment..  Safari Version 14.1.1 (16611.2.7.1.4) macOS Big Sur version 11.4

Comment: I have just downloaded firefox - still the same issue.

Comment: @michaeldibse take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43537290/16688813, this may help you